# Python: Plot a graph for NA vs Non-NA values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I want to generate a bar-plot for a column which will indicate frequency of na values vs frequency of Non-NA values in pandas.

My dataframe looks like:

```
df:

A          B
USA        10
Mexico     91
NA         44
Canada     42
NA         56
NA         31
India      99
Australia   87 
NA          65
```

My code plot's the graph but it is not able to differentiate between NA and Non-Na values.

Code:

```
 pd.value_counts(df['A']).plot.bar()
```

Comment: IIUC, Here's the starter code `na_freq = df[df.A.isnull()].B.sum(); pd.DataFrame({'NA': [na_freq],'Non-NA': [df.B.sum() - na_freq]})`

Comment: I don't wnt to perform summation on B value

Comment: What does your expected output looks like then? If not plot.

Comment: A plot describing frequency counts of 'NA' and Non-Na values for df['A']. Simply it would be two barplots ie one for NA and one for Non-NA or a histogram

Comment: Did you try the code I shared in the first comment? Is that where you like to proceed?